how to insert image using hexadecimal in postscript file
In the following PostScript file resource, there is already an image which displays correctly, but I need to replace it with a new image. I have the new image in JPEG format, and I use this tool https://capitalizemytitle.com/image-to-hex-converter/ to convert it to hexadecimal format.
After obtaining the hexadecimal value and replacing the existing hexadecimal code in the PostScript file (right after /Decode[0 1]/DataSource), the image doesn't display correctly in the PDF file generated by Ghostscript. This is how the image looks like.

Original Image:

I have also attached the working postscript resource file with the image data.
What could be going wrong? Also, what is the correct way to generate a hexadecimal value for image and use in this PostScript resource file?
    `%%BeginResource: file TestSignature150pix.jpg 1 0
    /GroupExecutive.form
    <<
    /FormType 1
    /BBox[0 0 139 82]
    /Matrix[1 0 0 1 0 0]
    /PaintProc{pop
            /DeviceGray setcolorspace gsave
        102.30 42.91 scale
            <<
            /Interpolate true
            /ImageType 1
            /Width 317
            /Height 133
            /ImageMatrix[317 0 0 -133 0 133]
            /BitsPerComponent 8
            /Decode[0 1]/DataSource
            <d5ff00fdffff00fcfbfefbff00fefcff00fcffff01fcfef9ff02fefffefeff
        05fefdfefffdfcfffffffc02fffcfefcff00feffff01fafbffff00fdfeff00
            fdfffbffff00fab6ff04fdfffefffcffff00fbfeff01fefdffff01fcfdffff
        00fdffff00fbfeff05fbf9fffafefffffdffff00fcfdff00feffff00fdfeff
        01fcfefeff00fdfffefeff00fd9bff00fefbff00fcfaff00feffff02fefdfe
            feff01fbfdfffefefffffdfeff01fdfcfffffffd03fbfafcfeffff01fefdf8
        ff02fcfbfeffff01fefbffff06f7fbfffdfefffaffff01f4fdb8ff07fefdff
            fafff7fffbfdff02fbfffdffff10fce4c7b4a28c7f8595bcc4bb9c87818a86
        ff840085ff861187868281807f8babccf6fff6cdbcc7e3fffeffff01fcfeff....`


If you are replacing the original data with a JPEG image then it won't work, because you haven't applied a DCTDecode filter to the image data. Your best bet will be to save the image data as an uncompressed bitmap, convert the image samples to hex data and then replace the hex string. You will also need to ensure that the width and height values in the dictionary are correct, as well as the colour space, Decode array, ImageMatrix and BitsPerComponent. The correct way to generate a hex string (not a single value, note) is to read each binary byte and write it as two ASCII bytes.
